# Can we have Web To Case Attachments?

Tags: apex, attachment

I have to add an attachment to a web to case form...

I know that we have form assembly app available... But is there any other way out?
I have referred
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008kj2IAA
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ac6EAA 
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h1kGAAQ
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000009A3CIAU
[Can we insert Attachments on a Case using Force.com Sites?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9193/can-we-insert-attachments-on-a-case-using-force-com-sites)

But I have not found any workable solution. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Web To Case can not accept Attachments.

You can use SOAP/Rest API to insert attachments with cases.

Comment: This is a good option, but if you are using a Salesforce edition that allows you to create Apex, it will probably be easier to use VF to accomplish this.

Comment: yes, you can create VF page and publish it on Site. That seems good approach. the only disadvantage to it would be you will not be able to put that vf page on your corporate site without using iFrame. And there are many potential problems with using iFrame. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice So the perfect answer would be it depends on your requirement :)